# corsFilter bean is not created due to BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a pretty typical method which would create a corsFilter bean in SpringBoot App, but when my server starts, I see the error saying BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException? Any help? Thanks

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedOrigins));
    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedHeaders));
    corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedMethods));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(corsFilterAllowedPathPattern, corsConfig);


    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;`
}
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'corsFilter' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.adaptBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]

the trace goes to SpringBoot framework and thus it is difficult to troubleshoot.Read a lot in the internet, but no luck

Comment: i dont really understand why you need your own custom cors filter, all you need to do is to configure the default one that already exists, all in accordance to the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code register a bean named `corsFilter` of type `FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>` but according to the exception message Spring searches for a bean named `corsFilter` of type `CorsFilter`.

You could try to change your code to

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedOrigins));
    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedHeaders));
    corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedMethods));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(corsFilterAllowedPathPattern, corsConfig);

    return new CorsFilter(source);    
}
```

Or, if you want to register the cors filter yourself you need to rename the bean:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilterRegistration() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedOrigins));
    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedHeaders));
    corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(delimitedStringToList(corsFilterAllowedMethods));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(corsFilterAllowedPathPattern, corsConfig);

    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Which variant you want to implement will depend on your needs:

- Spring usually orders their filter beans the way they think its best - if this is sufficient I would go with their default order
- If your needs differ from that you need to go with the manual filter registration

---

*Is "corsFilter" some sort of "reserved word" / "reserved bean name"?*

One could call it a "reserved bean name":

- Once you `@EnableWebSecurity` Spring Security uses `HttpSecurity`
- `HttpSecurity` uses a `CorsConfigurer` to add a `CorsFilter` to the Spring Security chain
- `CorsConfigurer` searches for a bean named "corsFilter". If it finds one it assumes that this is the `CorsFilter` it should configure and expects it to be of type `CorsFilter`.

Comment: Thomas, Thanks a lot! I already knew the first option and I did that in my code and I knew it worked,  but I didn't want to use that option because there was nowhere in that code to allow me to setOrder. I just tried your second option and this does work, and this option I liked it better. But can you do me a favor and help me to decide which option is better even though both worked?

Comment: @LittleLingzi it depends: if you are using Spring Security too: Spring Security contains code to order the filters in the way that the Spring Team thinks best (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterOrderRegistration.java) and in that case I would prefer not to mess with it. Without using Spring Security I might prefer the solution with defining the order myself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Thomas Kläger. I think I would go with your below option which renames my bean or methodName. But then when I exercised it a little more, I found out that with the same code content, the method name (BeanName) can be corsFilterRegistration() as you mentioned, and it can be anything, like xyz(), corsFilter1000(), all of them worked for me, but it just can not be corsFilter(), is that this corsFilter a reserved word by Spring or other reasons?

Comment: @LittleLingzi I've added some background information on why "corsFilter" is some kind of "reserved bean name*

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it and it makes great sense!